# How to pass the Different datas to webservice according to ScreenSize

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I need to pass the Different datas to webservice according to ScreenSize
eg:

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
        {  

        DeviceType=2;

     }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
    {     

        DeviceType=1;
    } 
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) 
    {     
            DeviceType=1;
    }
    else
    {
        DeviceType=2;
     }
```

I did this but unfortunately i didn't get correct value, I am getting the DeviceType as 0,
This happens only when any event fires.... As i need to show the images from webservice very soon when my app is started,Any ideas!!!

Answer (score 1):

Kalai i used this code to set layout on basis of screen size try this way might help you

```
Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

          if(display.getHeight()==480&&display.getWidth()==320){
              setContentView(new Grapic_m(this));

          }

          else if(display.getHeight()==800&&display.getWidth()==480){
             Grapic g=new Grapic(this);
          setContentView(g);

              }             
          else if(display.getHeight()==320&&display.getWidth()==240){

              setContentView(new Grapic_s(this));
```

Comment: @ AviKumar: Perfect... sounds Great man..Thank u..but i need to know which is for X-large,large,Medium and Small screens

Comment: have you seen this kalai http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html